# PHP postgres passing parameter

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am a rookie at PHP and I am using some existing code. The author of the code suggested to me:

```
// My lines
$_cp_sql .= " SET SESSION "."my.tech"." = :my_current_user";
$res_prepare = prepare_db($conn, $_cp_sql);
$res_bind = bind_param_db($res_prepare, ':my_current_user' , $current_user );
$res_ex = execute_prepared_db($res_prepare,0);
```

Note: prepare_db and all the other functions_db are PDO functions that the author created to be compatible with MYSQL, Postgres, and SQLITE.

My case is Postgres.  However the execute produces this error, and after days of reading, I still do not understand why.  What am I doing wrong?

```
The DBMS server said: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SET SESSION my.tech = $1 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with PostgreSQL. This is PHP, which is horrible at everything.

```
// My lines
$_cp_sql .= " SET SESSION "."my.tech"." = :my_current_user";
```

First that's the same as..

```
$_cp_sql .= " SET SESSION my.tech = :my_current_user";
```

Second, I don't think `SET` takes prepared statements. From [the docs on `PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)

> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement.

So feeding to `prepare_db` and `execute_prepared_db` a `SET` doesn't make any sense anyway.

Shy of that, `php` is a horrible language and I'm not even sure what provides you `prepare_db`, `bind_param_db`, or `execute_prepared_db`. I believe, despite the author intentions, that the author doesn't understand SQL. I would look for different code elsewhere.